# Javascript mouse click coordinates

Tags: javascript, events, onmousemove

I'm having problems trying to record the exact coordinates a click was made. The first readMouseMove function is working exactly how it is supposed to. Displaying the mouse coordinates when i scroll around. The second mouseClick function should record the coordinates only when a click is made. At the moment it's the same as the function above but it seems I can only use the clientx/y event once. Would there be a way to record the mouse click without having it be relative to an object somewhere?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function readMouseMove(e) {
        var xandy = 'x=' + e.clientX + " " +'y=' + e.clientY;
        document.getElementById('divOne').innerHTML = xandy;
    };
    function mouseClick(e) {
        var clickers = 'x=' + e.clientX + " " +'y=' + e.clientY;
        document.getElementById('divTwo').innerHTML = clickers;
    };
    function clearAll() {
        document.getElementById('divTwo').innerHTML = " "
    };
    document.onmousemove = readMouseMove;
    document = mouseClick;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are assigning a `mouseClick` to `document object`  here:

```
document = mouseClick;
```

Should be:

```
document.onclick = mouseClick;
```